# multiprocessing in nested loop not work properly in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, nested-loops

the code is like

```py
def function():
    for i in range(100):
        image1 = image_list[0,i]
        image2 = image_list[1,i]
        
         pool = Pool(3)
         for j in range(3):
            pool.apply_async(some_function, (image1, image2))
         pool.close()
         pool.join()
         do other stuff...
```

The function works fine when i=0, but when i=1 (the second round of main for loop), the pool seems not work properly (stop call some_function).

So how to process such multiprocessing task

Comment: Do you mean to create a pool for every `i` and to close it for every `j` ?

Answer (score 1):

See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

You should be creating the pool once, before the `for i in range(100:` rather than over and over again. And as you currently have your `for j in range(3):` block, after you call `apply_async` when `j` is 0 (i.e. the first time), you are immediately calling `pool.close()` and `pool.join()`. This will (1) block until that first submitted task completes and (2) prevent you from submitting any more tasks to the pool (i.e. for `j` equal to 2 and 3). What you want is closer to the following assuming you want to submit all 300 tasks and then wait for their completion:

```py
def function():
    pool = Pool()
    for i in range(100):
        image1 = image_list[0,i]
        image2 = image_list[1,i]
        for j in range(3):
            pool.apply_async(some_function, (image1, image2))
    # Wait for the 300 tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Note that we are no longer using a pool size of 3 but rather a pool size equal to the number of CPU cores we have since we are submitting all 300 tasks at once. I am also assuming that `some_function` is heavily CPU bound and so there is nothing to be gained by using a larger pool.

If, however, you want to submit tasks 3 at a time and wait for them to complete before submitting the next 3, then:

```py
def function():
    pool = Pool(3)
    for i in range(100):
        image1 = image_list[0,i]
        image2 = image_list[1,i]
        async_results = [pool.apply_async(some_function, (image1, image2)) for j in range(3)]
        # wait for all 3 tasks to complete without using pool.close()
        # and pool.join():
        for async_result in async_results:
            # Wait for this task to complete and get return value,
            # which we are not saving:
            async_result.get()
    # Only when we have finished submitting our 300 tasks do we cleanup
    # the pool:
    pool.close()
    pool.join
```

Note that I provided two versions of the code since you were not clear on what exactly you wanted to do. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).